# Как получить auth key из tdata

Tags: python, парсер, telegram

Как можно получить auth key из tdata в Telegram Desktop? В интернете нашел, что данные сессии хранятся в tdata\D877F783D5D3EF8C\map[0-1] и tdata\D877F783D5D3EF8C[0-1].